# Move ball in opposite direction

Tags: android, move, translate-animation

I have to image buttons in shape of two balls I want to move ball in opposite direction as it get hit by other ball.it is moving alright when it collide with other but i want to move ball in opposite direction. Thanks in Advance

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                final View dragView1 = findViewById(R.id.ib1);

                Rect rect=new Rect();
                view.getHitRect(rect);
                Rect rect1=new Rect();
                dragView1.getHitRect(rect1);

                if(Rect.intersects(rect,rect1)) {

                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setRepeatMode(0);
                    dragView1.startAnimation(animation);}

                break;
```